# How to bind dependency property of ICommand of ItemsControl member to parent view model?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a custom user control that has a checkbox and a button with backing dependency properties.

I also have a window with an ItemsControl and I bind that control's "ItemsSource" to an ObservableCollection containing said user controls.

My goal is to be able to access the dependency properties in the window's view model, so I can check whether the checkbox of each member of the collection is checked or not and when the user clicks the button - remove the user control containing the button from the collection.

#### This is my code

User control XAML:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding cbChecked,
            Mode=OneWayToSource,
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
            AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>


<Button Content="X"
        Command="{Binding RemoveCommand,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                    AncestorType=UserControl}}">
```

(note I am not sure if I need the "UpdateSourceTrigger")

User control codebehind:

```
    public ICommand RemoveCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(RemoveCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RemoveCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for RemoveCommand.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RemoveCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RemoveCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CustomUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(OnAnyPropertyChanged));

    public bool cbChecked
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(cbCheckedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(cbCheckedProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for cbChecked.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty cbCheckedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("cbChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(OnAnyPropertyChanged));

    static void OnAnyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        => (obj as CustomUserControl).OnAnyPropertyChanged(args);

    void OnAnyPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        => AnyPropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
```

Window XAML:

```
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Row="0">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ControlsCollection}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="5,20,0,0"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

How can I make it so when the user clicks the "X" button the user control that holds it is removed from the collection AND be able to check the checkbox "checked" status from the window's view model?

Comment: Where is your binding source? You must post it too. Where/how do you use your UserControl? It's not in your example too. Simply bind the `cbChecked` property to the data source (DataContext of the UserControl). This data source must also define the ICommand implementation and source collection. And don't wrap the ItemsControl into a ScrollViewer. Instead use a ListBox, which alread provides scrolling and in addition has a superior performance (as it internally uses UI virtualization).

Comment: The UserControl probably should not raise/define a AnyPropertyChanged event. It appears like your data source is observing this event. Don't define UserControls in your data source. Instead in WPF you should always use [DataTemplates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/styles-templates-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#datatemplates), [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). The UserControl should be part of this template to visualize the data models of the ListBox

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, you should not hold an element of view in view model. The item of ObservableCollection should be item's view model rather than UserControl.

Second, you don't need to use a UserControl in such case. A DataTemplate which has the same elements will suffice.

For example, a minimal item's view model would be as follows.

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

public partial class ItemViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public bool _checked;
}
```

Then, window's view model.

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Input;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;

public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> ItemsCollection { get; } = new();

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ItemsCollection.Add(new ItemViewModel());
        ItemsCollection.Add(new ItemViewModel());
        ItemsCollection.Add(new ItemViewModel());
    }

    public ICommand RemoveCommand => _removeCommand ??= new RelayCommand<ItemViewModel>(item => Remove(item));
    private RelayCommand<ItemViewModel>? _removeCommand;

    private void Remove(ItemViewModel? item)
    {
        if (item is not null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Checked:{item.Checked}");

            ItemsCollection.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

The window's view. The elements of DataTemplate of ItemsControl.ItemTemplate are the same as your UserControl but bindings are modified.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="600" Height="300">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="5,20,0,0"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
                        <Button Content="X"
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Comment: What is ObservableObject? I don't think it is a good idea to introduce a 3rd party dependency in an answer. You should address the environment of the original question.

Comment: @BionicCode Thanks for your question. CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel.ObservableObject is a part of .NET Community Toolkit which is developed by including Microsoft and the latest of this kind of toolkit. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-the-dotnet-community-toolkit-800/